# Asp.Net GridView not getting disabled

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my application i am using a `GridView` and i am adding an onlick attribute to the GridView through the following Code..

```
  Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)


    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex.ToString())
    End If
```

When someone selects a row in the Grid view, i want the GridView to get disabled and not allow any other selections unless the user presses a button. I tried using

`GridView1.Enabled = false`

But still the user is able to select a row.

How can i **disable** the `GridView Selection` ??

Comment: can you show the code you execute to disable the grid? is that server side? can you debug and see if it gets called?

Comment: try this, put grid inside an `<asp:panel>` and disable the panel.

Comment: @DavidePiras I am calling it from Server Side and the code is getting called  .

Comment: @Furqan : Tried that but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are selecting a row by the above code the easiest fix would be to check if selected index is not equal to -1 (meaning a row has been selected) in the row databound event.

```
If GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString())
    End If
End If
```

and to reattach the selecting code on the click of a button you can just set the selectedIndex to -1 and rebind the gridview in the button click event.